# Fastest way to extract html from Chromedriver

Tags: python, html, selenium-chromedriver

I need a fast way of extracting the html-code for a specific table using Chromedriver with selenium in python. So far I have found that this option

```
table_data = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='cell-table']").get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

is slightly faster than this option

```
table_data = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='cell-table']").text
```

and both options give me the html-code I need. This option is significantly faster

```
table_data = webdriver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//table[@class]/tbody/tr")
```

however, as far as I can tell, for each row in `table_data` it needs the following code to actually get access to the html-data:

```
for row in table_data:
        row.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Which is quite slow. Seems like does it actually goes back to the browser to extract the html-code for each row?

Does anyone have suggestions on how to extract the html-code for a table in a faster way? Due to my setup I need to use Chromedriver.

Comment: Does `find_elements()` return a generator or a list?  I'm asking as I don't really know. If it returns a generator then one might be obtaining a lazy `table_data`.

Comment: the array returned by find_elements() lookes something like this: [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="59b3b9e75ac96f02eef2a42c21475c39", element="c727325e-676a-4a44-80fc-996f22b7c20a")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="59b3b9e75ac96f02eef2a42c21475c39", element="a9a30168-3970-4218-999f-1d3fac15ccc9")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="59b3b9e75ac96f02eef2a42c21475c39", element="14ce9ee1-2462-45bd-be53-09b28fb49f96")>]

Comment: @JonSG `find_elements()` actually returns a list of references to physical elements, as I described in the answer here

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your guess is correct. Selenium WebElement object is just a reference, a pointer to the physical web element on the web page. So, applying actions like `row.get_attribute('innerHTML')` you are passing Selenium a reference `row`, Selenium accesses the web page, accesses the physical web element according to passed WebElement parameter and retrieves it attribute.
So, code like this:

```py
for row in table_data:
    row.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

will actually access the web page at least `len(table_data)` times. And yes, this will take some time.
So, if you are looking for the fastest way you need to use

```py
table_data = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='cell-table']").text
```

As you mentioned this is slightly faster than

```py
table_data = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='cell-table']").get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Are there alternative ways of speeding up extracting the html? Options for Chromedriver etc?

Comment: Yes. This can be done much faster. But not with Selenium. The data can be received by direct API calls from server. Also this can be done with scraping tools like bs4. Unfortunately I'm less familiar with scraping tools, I'm automation engineer. You can ask this question again asking how to do that faster, as I mentioned. Commenting below existing question not visible for all the other users here, so it's better to ask a new question so it will appear at the top of their feed